# Was: Calling all cachebusters! Now: how can I delay ajax call until my image div is empty?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, css-transitions, browser-cache

UPDATE 2:  Sorry, but I'm not sure how best to update this...whether through editing the original, or adding my own comments below.  Steer me correctly?

I've decided to repost this as a new question, as I've changed a few things and don't want more red herring attempts or time wasting chasing down the wrong path.

Right or wrong, the repost is titled:  "Original question was  "Calling all Cachebusters" ....now - "Can I delay ajax call until div is empty?"

following is the original post....I recommend you find the updated one...

UPDATE:  Red Herring alert.  This is not a cache issue but simply a loop issue with my next/previous buttons when they get to the end of the content.  Yes, there's some odd Alert behavior but I'm ignoring that now, pursuing a fix for the next/prev loop.   Sorry, and hopefully no one has seen this yet.

I'm leaving the content following up for now, but will update once I figure out

I've been beating my head against a wall for a few days trying to fix a gnarly artifact in my image slideshow solution. I thought I was on track to a fix as this really seems to be an ajax browser cache problem, but perhaps not?  After looking through stackoverflow I've tried every approach I can find: JSONP with GET and cache = false, cache-control "no store", even a cachebusting timestamp, and an ajaxSetup cache-false, all to no avail.

I'll have to post only part of the code as I've set this up in an MVC structure and have multiple file includes....so bear with me as I try to explain.  This seems complicated, but ***it all works brilliantly***, (both Chrome and FF) up until.....it doesn't.

Overview:

My page has a series of menu links each of which sets a different "category id" for the ajax call.  My page has an empty imagediv into which I add the img elements programmatically, based on the JSON data returned from a MYSQL db query.  I have prev and next controls to view the images one at a time, using a cross-fade transition managed by css opacity.

Here's a rundown of how it works:

1. Selecting one of the links executes my Ajax function, which calls actions.php passing the category ID.
2. actions.php does a MYSQL db query using the category id and returns a list of matching image urls in JSONP format (initially this was JSON but I switched to JSONP in a vain attempt thinking I could take advantage of cache=false default).
3. The ajax success function also creates one img element for each of the urls, and sets the first to opaque via CSS (all others are transparent via CSS).
4. I can then display the images one at a time using my next/previous buttons, via the next and prev functions.
5. I have implemented a cross-fade transition by adding/removing a css class to change opacity..
6. When I get to the end of the img elements it loops back to the other end, and works both forward and reverse.

Now this all works absolutely brilliantly, but only for the first category link I select.

Now the weird stuff begins.  If I select a ***different link*** on the page to retrieve a different set of images, I can again use next/previous, but when I get to the end of the images, I suddenly have 2 superimposed images (seems two of the images are opaque at the same time).

I also added an alert to track what's going on, and the odd thing is that the alert is fired multiple times!!  Every time I select a new category link, the alert "builds" until I have a dozen or more which all fire successively with a single "next" or "previous" click.

Going to another page and coming back solves the problem - until I again select a ***second-nth*** category.

It seems there's some cacheing of the image (and the alert?) that's impossible to purge...so I'm not sure this is an ajax cache issue, but what else could it be?  And what else can I try??

Here's the main link function call with the ajax call inside.  I've added comments to help clarify:

```
$(".nav-link").click(function() {

       var category = $(this).attr("data-categoryid");  //link which sets the category

       //set timestamp to avoid caching??
       var tsTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();

       //getImageData accesses MYSQL and returns JSONP encoded list of image urls which are stored in my server filesystem
       //for the specified category typeid   

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "actions.php?action=getImageData&?cachebuster=" + new Date().getTime() + "",  //tried to use a cache buster! didn't work.
            data: "categoryid= " + category,
            time: "tsTimeStamp",
            headers: {"Cache-Control": "no-store"},
            dataType: 'jsonp',

            success: function(result) {
                $("#imagediv").empty(); //empty the previous imagediv of all img contents (attempt to avoid the cacheing issues!!!!)
                var imagearray = [];             

                for (i=0; i< result.length; i++) {

                    imagearray.push(result[i]["url"]);

                    //create the img elements and append to the imagediv container
                    var $img = $( "<img class='img-fluid main-image myImage mx-auto d-block nextimage'  id='myImage' src='" + imagearray[i] + "' >");
                    $("#imagediv").append($img);     
                }

                //set the first image to opaque...all others default to opacity=0 via css
                $("#imagediv img").eq(0).addClass("opaque");

                //if there's only one image url in the results, hide the next/previous buttons
                if (result.length > 1) {$("#centerdiv").show();} else {$("#centerdiv").hide();}

                var imageIndex = 0;

                $("#next").click(function(){
                    $("#imagediv img").eq(imageIndex).removeClass("opaque");

                    alert($("#imagediv").length + " " + imageIndex); //note that this alert fires 3 times on a 2-nth category search!!!

                    imageIndex +=1;

                    //if at end of array, loop back to beginning - that's when I get 2 images superimposed but only on the 2-nth category search!!
                    if (imageIndex == result.length) {
                        imageIndex = 0;
                    }

                    $("#imagediv img").eq(imageIndex).addClass("opaque");

                });

                $("#previous").click(function(){
                    alert(imageIndex);
                    $("#imagediv img").eq(imageIndex).removeClass("opaque");

                    imageIndex -=1;

                    //if going in "reverse" and at beginning of array, loop back to the end
                    if (imageIndex == -1) {
                        imageIndex = result.length-1;
                    }

                    $("#imagediv img").eq(imageIndex).addClass("opaque");

                });



            },  cache: false,
        }) 

    });
```

There must be something very simple happening here...related to reaching the end of the image array(?) but again, it all works brilliantly for "first time" use.  Only when I go to another category do I start to see the superimposed images and get those multiple alert messages.

Wish I could put this up on a fiddle for you to see.  Worst case I can share the link to my website but that would only work temporarily....

Here's the actions.php code with the JSONP encode.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'getImageData') {

  if ($_GET) {

    $myid = $_GET['categoryid'];

    $whereClause = "WHERE menucategoryid = ".$_GET['categoryid']. "";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM images" .$whereclause. "";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

        echo "Nothing to display.";

    } else  {

        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM images ".$whereClause."";
        //for each image returned by the above query, 
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $url = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {

          $url[] = array(

              'url' => $row['imageurl'],
              'title' =>$row['title'],
              'caption' => $row['caption']


          );

        }

         echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($url, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).')';

    } 

  }

}
```

Comment: The .click() does not remove any previous click handler function, it just adds another one...

Comment: Thanks John, I saw that response after I created the new question which was answered similarly by Jaromanda.  Perfect solution....and it explains all the funky behavior of superimposed images and so forth.   Thanks again.